# How to exclude id from an URL using PHP and htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite url using .htacces.
The script below reproduces following url:
**www.mysite.com/my-category/fany-pink-id-35-lang-en.html**

Now I would like to exclude the **id** and the **lang** from the URL in order to obtain following link:
**www.mysite.com/my-category/fany-pink.html**

The **id** and the **lang** are variable which I need to show the selected product in a specific language.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule my-category(.*)(.*)-id-(.*)-lang-(.*)\.html$ product-details.php?    descr=$1&product=$2&id=$3&lang=$4
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to create a permanent redirect from all the requests like www.mysite.com/my-category/fany-pink-id-35-lang-en.html to www.mysite.com/my-category/fany-pink.html or leave the requests as is but parse id and lang attributes as a GET variables to a script?

Comment: Hi,
I want to create a permanent redirect from all the requests like www.mysite.com/my-category/fany-pink-id-35-lang-en.html to www.mysite.com/my-category/fany-pink.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule to redirect is pretty simple:

```
RewriteRule my-category/(.*)-id-(.*)-lang-(.*)\.html$ /my-category/$1.html [L,R=301]
```

However I'm wondering how are you gonna obtain id and language attributes now if the aren't present in the url anymore?